# Dirichlet problem on a half-plane

Tags: partial-differential-equations, greens-function

I have a Dirichlet problem on a half-plane

$\begin{equation*}
 \begin{cases}
   \Delta{u}=0, y>0
   \\
   u(x,0) = \frac{x}{1+x^2}, y =0
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}$

And in solving this PDE I have integral and answer, but the author doesn't show how he solved this problem

$u(x_0, y_0, z_0)=-\frac{y}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{x}{1+x^2} \frac{1}{(x-x_0)^2+y^2_0} dx=\frac{x_0}{x_0^2 + (1+y_0)^2}$

I want to take the integral but I don't know what $x_0 \; and\; y_0$ means when I take the integral. The author wrote that solved by "The theory of residue integrals". But I don't know why he uses it here because here we don't have complex numbers.

Comment: May you check if you wrote down the answer to that integral correctly? Improper integrals with respect to $x$ do not have solutions that depend on $x$.

Comment: Yes i think you right, I changed x to x_0 and y to y_0

Comment: That answer still doesn't seem correct even after the edit. I tested this numerically for multiple values of $x_0$ and $y_0$ and the equation doesn't hold true.

Comment: @Accelerator i also forget to add $\frac{y}{\pi}$

Comment: I think $\dfrac{y}{\pi}$ should be $\dfrac{y_0}{\pi}$. One way to avoid using the complex analysis is to find constants $A, B, C$ and $D$ such that $\dfrac{x}{1+x^2} \dfrac{1}{(x-x_0)^2 + y_0^2} = \dfrac{Ax+B}{1+x^2} + \dfrac{Cx+D}{(x-x_0)^2 + y_0^2}$.